# CUDA array elements shifting operation

Tags: arrays, cuda, shift

I'm currently performing an array shifting operation on CUDA but I'm stuck at the part where I would need to parallelize the operation on the GPU (I've already done it for CPU).  So, the operation is basically shifting elements in the array.

So for example if I have a M by N matrix, for each row if I see a -1, I would replace
the -1 with the element next to it, and so on until I hit the end of the row, and I 
need to do that for all columns in parallel.

So for a quick example:

```
 3  4  1 -1  5  6  7  8
-1  4  5  2  1  2  5  2
 2  4  5  1  2  3  4 -1
```

for that matrix, the resulting matrix would be:

```
 3  4  1  5  6  7  8  8
 4  5  2  1  2  5  2  2
 2  4  5  1  2  3  4 -1
```

PS. The last element remains the same because it hits the boundary where it has nothing to
   replace with.  Also, only one -1 will appear in each row

So, that's basically the operation, but my question is how do I assign a thread to each row
or .. parallelize all the rows and do this shifting at the same time in cuda?  Also, my 
array is converted from a 2d array to a 1d array using the equation

```
array1d[i+width*j]  =  array2d[i][j];
```

So far I've tried this:

```
__global__ void gpu_shiftArray(int *Arr, int *location, int width, int height)
{
int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

int index = i+width*j;

//shift when I see -1
if(Arr[index] == -1)
{
    Arr[index] = (index % height) ? Arr[index+1] : 
    }
    //location stores the index of -1, so anything after the -1 will be shifted too
if((location[i]+width*j) <= index)
{
    Arr[index] = (index % height) ? Arr[index+1] : 
}
}
```

The output of it is not exactly correct (off by like 5-10 values) but I'm not exactly sure 
why nor I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Do you ever have more than one -1 per row?  What is the rule for filling in the values on the right after shifting?  Do you always duplicate the last value? What if there are multiple -1s in the row?

Comment: The OP already clarified that the -1 only occurs once per row. And the scheme seems to be move everything to the left after -1, but leave the right most element as is.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be done with a slightly modified "stream compaction" algorithm that uses a "predicate sum" as a primitive. See the following link for details:
[Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).

Hmm.   I can see that there could also be advantages to using the ballot functions (comparing source data to -1) and some bit arithmetic to determine how (and if) warp threads select the destination offsets when it does the copy.